# How to declare a variable at the bottom of the page and use its value at the top?

Tags: php

It maybe easy to do but I am new to php.
I really need to know how to solve it.

$first = $second;

$second = 4;

I need to pass the value of $second to $first dynamically whenever it changes.

please help,

Thanks

Comment: as I know, php will execute and process the code in logical order it will appear at runtime. You need to store the variable inside the database if you want to retrive it later.

Answer (score -1):

First, your question is purely PHP, I do not see a relationship with WordPress.
If you want to link the two variables, you must use what is called: [Passing by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

In your case :

```
$first = & $second
```